# How to serve stylesheet in Django

Tags: css, django

i want to use css in Django templates..If i give CSS with in the templates it gets working.
But i want to use in static serve manner.

settings.py

```
       DEBUG =True
       MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/WorkBase/Python/first/static/'
       MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
       ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

```
      'C:/WorkBase/Python/first/templates',
       )
```

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (

```
      'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
      'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
      'django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source',
```

)

urls.py

```
        from django.conf import settings

        if settings.DEBUG:
                urlpatterns +=patterns(' ',
                (r'^static/(?p<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

)

I got  'unexpected end of pattern' error for above line

```
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the 'P' to name the pattern needs to be capitalized. `r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$'`

All of the examples and doc show it capitalized.  [Python Regex Doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

[T. Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727578/how-to-serve-stylesheet-in-django/1727874#1727874) has hit the nail on the head with his answer. Here's what I use, for an example:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += patterns('',
                (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                        { 'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")}),
        )
```